# How to render nested JSON inside JSX in react native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, jsx

I want to list the json response. How do i render nested json inside my jsx?
following is json response

```
[{
    "data": {
        "total_students": 13,
        "seats": "",
        "categories": [{
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Economy",
            "slug": "economy",
        }],
        "instructor": {
            "id": "24",
            "name": "Ad",
            "sub": ""
        },
        "menu_order": 0
    },
    "headers": [],
    "status": 200
}
```

This is how the response looks like. Also rendering in react is as shown below

```
return this.state.user.map(user =>

        <CardSection>
        <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
        <Text key= {user.data.name} style={styles.userStyle}>{this.state.user.data}</Text>
        </View>
        </CardSection>
```

I have tried like the above but getting error in rendering part `cannot define name of undefined`.What wrong am i doing?please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a key `name` in `data` object that `undefined` If you want to nested JSON you can access like

- name in instructor : `user.data.instructor.name`
- name in categories (array) : `user.data.categories.map(category => category.name)`

Answer (score 1):

`user.data.name` does not seem to be present in your JSON response. The name could be `user.data.instructor.name`.